# Failed to unmount /var and /var/lib when shutting down or rebooting ubuntu

Tags: 22.04, unmount

I am having issues with an error message when shutting down or rebooting my Ubuntu 22.04.3 server.

On screen I can see that during shutdown `/var` and `/var/lib` which are on seperate partitions cannot be unmounted. I found out that it could be because of systemd-journald.service tries to log till the end of the shutdown. Therefore the mountpoint is busy and cannot be unmounted.

I wasn't able to find useful work-arounds and I was kind of amazed that there is so little information about this on the internet.
I also tried to set up a virtual box and as soon as `/var` is on a different partition, it fails to unmount when turning off.

My question now:
Can logs get corrupted when `/var` and/or `/var/lib` cannot be unmounted?
Will it try to unmount the mountpoints in a later phase without displaying it?

In my specific use-case logs are very important.

As a possible work-around I was thinking of moving the rotated logs to a different partition with something like a cron-job but when there is the option to move the whole `/var` partition to a different partition ...

Comment: Your configuration. is not valid (`/var` on separate partition), for just this reason. See the Filesystem Hierarcy Standard at `https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml`, or read `man hier`.

Comment: Sorry, no clue what you mean or want to tell me. I dont think that my "configuration" is "invalid" when setting up partitions like that

Comment: If I'm reading it right, this does seem to be a longstanding known issue [/var stays busy at shutdown due to journald #867](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/867) - possibly worked around via a .override?

Comment: If systemd doesn't support a well-established *nix partitioning scheme, imho that's a bug not a "configuration problem"

Comment: I also found the bug #867 that @steeldriver mentioned but I was wondering how this bug cannot be solved by now when thinking of that the bug is closed. I tried several suggestions in the unit-file of systemd-journald.service and systemd-journal-flush.service but it did not help.